# How to start with $\pi$ defined as the area of the unit circle.

Tags: geometry, axioms

In IV-1, Example 3 of Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, by C. E. Edwards Jr. the reader is told *"Since $\pi$ is by definition the area of the unit circle,...".*

The example provides a proof that $A=\pi r^2$, so that result cannot be used to justify the (unconventional) definition.

Every definition of $\pi$ I have seen in mathematical literature amounts to:

*Given a circle of diameter $D$ and circumference $C$, the real number $\pi$ is defined as $\pi=\frac{C}{D}$.*

I could propose a number of alternative ways of defining $\pi$. For example, Wallis's product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product .  From there one must demonstrate that $\pi$ so defined satisfies $\pi=\frac{C}{D}$.

Similarly, the definition promulgated by Edwards must result in $\pi=\frac{C}{D}$.  I'm sure I could provide persuasive arguments toward this end.  What I would like to know is whether there is an established convention for demonstrating that Edwards's definition of $\pi$ is equivalent to the traditional form I stated above.

In particular, I am interested to know how this has been done without the use of trigonometry nor calculus.

---

Edit to add: This is my heuristic argument showing $2\pi r=C$. Assuming $A=\pi r^2$.

For a small change in radius $\Delta r$ there will be a corresponding change in circumference $\Delta C$. The change in area will be the area of an annulus

$\Delta A=\pi(r-\Delta r)^{2}-\pi r^{2}=\pi(2r\Delta r+\Delta r^{2})=(C+\varepsilon)\Delta r$.

Where $0<\varepsilon<\Delta C$.

The last expression follows from the observation that $(C+\Delta C)\Delta r>\Delta A>C\Delta r$. That is, $\Delta A$ falls somewhere between the area of a rectangle $C\times\Delta r$ and the area of a rectangle $(C+\Delta C)\times\Delta r$. The last two expressions in the above equivalence result in

$2\pi r+\pi\Delta r=C+\varepsilon$.

Clearly $\varepsilon\to0$ as $\Delta r\to0$. So what remains is

$2\pi r=C$.

Comment: I don't know that you need an established convention.  Once you've proved from his definition that the circumference is 2$\pi r$, then you have everything you need to conclude that $\pi=\frac{C}{D}$ and thus you have your equivalence.

Comment: Well, do you know a proof that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ given the definition $\pi=C/D$?  That proves that the two definitions are equivalent.  In any case, there definitely does not exist an "established convention" for proving this.  Established conventions are normally for things like definitions and notation, not proofs.

Comment: How do you find the area of a general circle without calculus?

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/kevinknudson/2015/12/03/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-pi-part-3-the-area-of-a-circle/#58a16eec38c7

Comment: In rigorous developments, I think a more common definition of $\pi$ is something like "half the period of a nonzero solution to the differential equation $y''=-y$" or "twice the smallest $x$ such that $\cos x=0$, where $\cos$ is defined by its power series".

Comment: It has been proved a few years ago that, in a circle, the ratio between the circumference and the diameter is the same as the ratio between the area and the square of the radius: Archimedes did it.

Comment: Somos I would partially fill the unit circle with an inscribed regular polygon of an even number of sides.  I would cut it into triangles with vertices at the center, then lay them side-by-side with their vertices alternating up and down to form a parallelogram.  I would then argue that every finer approximation would more closely resemble a rectangle of base C/2 and height 1.  Since I am assuming the circumference of the unit circle is defined as $2\pi$ the area is $\pi$.  Then I will argue that the circumference varies linearly with radius so a similar rectangle will have area $A=\pi r^2$.

Comment: @Steven Hatton That is essentially Caculus, the finding of limiting values of quantities.